# Darken the arrows below the magnified image

Tags: php, frontend, image, html

Here's a screen shot from the bottom of a product page, magnified image, in Shopify. Please zoom in the image. Notice that the < X > is very faint.  Sometimes on some pages, they're almost invisible.  Can you help darken them or somehow make them more visible?  It doesn't need to be dramatic, but just so that they are more obvious.

https://reflectperfection.com/collections/vanity-mirrors/products/kimball-young-mirror-image-3x-stylish-cava-makeup-mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the stroke-width of your SVG
like below

```
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--next RoundButton" data-animate-right="" title="Next (right arrow)"><svg class="Icon Icon--arrow-right" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 11 21">
      <polyline fill="none" stroke="currentColor" points="0.5 0.5 10.5 10.5 0.5 20.5" stroke-width="3.25"></polyline>
    </svg></button>
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, I would prefer a solution involving CSS. thanks